# Why arp ignore/annouce are not enable by default

Tags: linux, debian, arp

I have a specific question which need experience for an answer:

Why arp_ignore / arp_announce are not enable by default on linux installation (debian for example) is there a specific reason ?

Which interest to receive arp answer from wrong network interfaces ?

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Answer (score 5):

That's not Debian specific, the default is from Linux.

Check https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=168960 and the response from [David Miller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_S._Miller):

> This behavior is consistent with the Linux IPV4 stack's adherence to
> the host based model of IPV4 address instead of the interface based
> model which is pretty much what you are asking for.
>
> Both addressing models are described by the RFCs and are completely
> valid.
>
> This should not be changed and is not a bug.  If you want different
> behavior, the tunables are there for you to tweak, but that does not
> make them right for everyone as a default.

See [RFC 1122, 3.3.4.2  Multihoming Requirements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#section-3.3.4.2) (Strong ES model, Weak ES model).